# SAS lag exclude missing values?

Tags: sas, lag

Does anyone know how to use lag in SAS that only takes into account the last known numbers from a variable, and not missing values I.e not the "." in the following sequence: 9, 10, 8, ., 7?

```
data have;
  input val;
  datalines;
9
10
8
.
7
;
run;
```

I would like a table containing the following:

```
val  want_val
9    9
10   10
8    8
.    8 
7    7
```

Comment: This is not a SAS programming question, but a question on how to use SAS procedures to transform data. I recommend you post over at communities.sas.com with non-programming questions. As a good place to start, look at PROC EXPAND and the possible transformation options. That will allow you to achieve your goal.

Comment: This reads to me like the start of a programming question.  Suggest you give sample data, and describe the output data you would want.  Also show any code you have tried, and why it didn't work.  Sounds like maybe you are trying to do "last observation carry forward" instead of a simple lag.  Googling SAS LOCF could help with ideas.

Comment: I don't see how this isn't a programming question... it's not very detailed, but it's probably better than half the questions here.

Comment: I do think you need a clearer *have* and *want*, with more data in it, to get the answer that you need.

Comment: I've taken a guess at the have + want datasets.  @Sasmania if that's not what you are trying to do then please let us know.

Comment: Thanks Robert thats what i needed!

Answer (score 0):

Use conditional logic instead of a lag function directly.

1. Create a lagged variable using lag function
2. Create another variable that takes the lagged function ONLY IF the value is not missing.

   ```
   data have;
   input y;
   cards;
   9 
   10 
   8
   .
   7
   ;


   data want;
   set have;
   retain x_lag;
   x=lag(y);
   if x ne . then x_lag=x;
   run;

   proc print data=want;
   var y x_lag;
   run;
   ```

OUTPUT:

```
                                   Obs     y    x_lag

                                    1      9       .
                                    2     10       9
                                    3      8      10
                                    4      .       8
                                    5      7       8
```

Comment: Seems like the exact same result can be obtained without using `lag`, no?  Just retain and set it after the output?

Comment: Depends on what else is being done in the step.  If only the lag then that would work, but if you're doing other processing there could be some issues.

Comment: I don't understand your comment "Depends" and I ran the code, it doesn't appear to work.   I agree with Joe LAG is not good for LOCF.

Comment: I'm interpreting the question differently than @Robert, so the OP would need to clarify. If Roberts interpretation is correct then my code does not work.

Answer (score 0):

This could be a situation where using an `IF` statement with `LAG` is a good idea.  Once you understand how the two statements work together you can use them to your advantage (or avoid a common pitfall).  I recommend reading [this](http://www.lexjansen.com/nesug/nesug07/cc/cc33.pdf) for further details.

In the meantime, does this code do what you want?

```
data lags;
input num;
if not missing(num) then lag_num = lag(num);
datalines;
9
10
8
.
7
;
run;
```

Comment: This isn't *quite* right, most likely (though the question isn't super clear there).  Most use cases need the lag_num filled on every row with the most recent nonmissing.